# Create a sub database within rails application to store data in sub database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails application requirement which I have User table in main database and need to create UserJobs related records(sub tables) with in a sub database , i.e I need to create a different database for each user and store their Jobs in a different database. 
How can I do this manually from rails application.

Answer (score 0):

[`Apartment`](https://github.com/influitive/apartment) gem could come in handy. It lets you create multiple `schemas` in `database` with the ability of supporting `multi-tenancy`.

Answer (score 0):

Apartment Gem would do all the things for you which you want to do as mentioned in your query.